# Keras - Connecting Functional API models together

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to connect 2 functional API models together. here's the summary of the 2 models:

The First "Input" Model (It works as a single model just fine):

[image: model1]

The Second Model that is supposed to be connected to the first model:

[image: model2]

I'm trying to connect them together like this:

```
model = Model(input=generator.input, output=[discriminator.output[0], discriminator.output[1]])
```

But I get this error:

> Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor discriminator_input
>   at layer "discriminator_input". The following previous layers were
>   accessed without issue: []

I tried to make a model out of them like this:

```
Model(input=[generator.input, discriminator.input], output=[discriminator.output[0], discriminator.output[1]])
```

But this code just resulted in the second Model (and not the 2 of them together), or at least this is what I think after getting a summary of the model and plotting it's structure.

can we do this in Keras (connecting functional API models) or is there another way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question on the Keras Github page and [here's the thread](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4205) about how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think model should accept layer while your are trying to pass a tensor?
You should try following discussions because I too had issues regarding timedistributed layers though. https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4178
and https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2609

Comment: thanks for the response... but I had already checked them before posting this question and they don't answer it... the only thing I could do with them was to follow them in hopes of someone continuing the discussion... I want to know the possibilities when making a new Model based on models which have been made with the Functional API in Keras...

Comment: I assume this is not solved yet? I have same issue here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/szAvryNqHqU

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and with help got it fixed. Have a look here: [Stacking models in Class Model API](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/szAvryNqHqU).